# apt-get failed install of libg15, all package management is failing

Tags: 10.04, apt, package-management, uninstall

I was trying to get my Logitech G510 keyboard's back-lights working so I went into the Synaptic Package Manager and marked LibG15, G15daemon, and all the other associated packages.  Synaptic reported a failed install. Now all Package management is failing due to libg15 being "halfway installed."
Some commands I have tried to fix the problem follow. . .

```
root@bt:~# apt-get upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: The package libg15 needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.

root@bt:~# sudo apt-get autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: The package libg15 needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.


root@bt:~# sudo apt-get -f purge libg15
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: The package libg15 needs to be reinstalled, but I can't find an archive for it.

root@bt:~# sudo dpkg --configure -a
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of g15macro:
 g15macro depends on g15daemon; however:
  Package g15daemon is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing g15macro (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of g15stats:
 g15stats depends on g15daemon; however:
  Package g15daemon is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing g15stats (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 g15macro
 g15stats
```

I'm not too computer savvy. Any help would be much appreciated!!!
Note: I'm using Ubuntu 10.04 under Backtrack 5 R3.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem!

I did a quick edit of `/var/lib/dpkg/status` and removed the half installed package information. After that I was able to open synaptic and purge all of the packages associated with G15.

Comment: Thanks! Had a similar issue with gish, totally locked up my upgrades. Removing the lines related to that package from /var/lib/dpkg/status also solved my issue.